# RxJs forkJoin several observables in a row

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

**UPDATE :**

I have a problem that I cannot resolve.

In my code, I have an objects list.
For each of the objects, I have to chain 3 requests in a row and not at the same time. But each objects could be done in parallel.

So I am using a `forkjoin` to execute code when the queries are complete.
But the loop executes all the procedures ignoring the errors.

---

So I changed my code below and the 3 procedures run well in succession.

However, in the event of an error, the catchError is not taken into account.
The code therefore connects procedure 1 then 2 and 3, even if 1 is in error.

The procedure3 this.store.proc3 (input3, "ERR") must be executed even after an error.

```
this.list.forEach(obj => {
    var input1 = obj...;
    var input2 = obj...;
    var input3 = obj...;
    
    var obs = this.store.input1(input1).pipe(
        catchError(err1 => this.store.proc3(input3, "ERR")),
        concatMap(res1 => this.store.proc2(input2).pipe(
            catchError(err2 => this.store.proc3(input3, "ERR"),
            concatMap(res2 => this.store.proc3(input3, "OK")
        ))
    );
    _obs$.push(obs);
}

forkJoin(_obs$).subscribe(
    results => {
        if(results) {
            this._dialogRef.close(true);
            // ...
        }
    }
);
```

> *CURRENT CASE :*
>
> - proc1 OK -> proc2 OK -> proc3(OK)
> - proc1 OK -> proc2 ERR -> proc3(OK)
> - proc1 ERR -> proc2 ERR -> proc3(OK)

> *DESIRED CASE :*
>
> - proc1 OK -> proc2 OK -> proc3(OK)
> - proc1 OK -> proc2 ERR -> proc3(ERR)
> - proc1 ERR -> proc3(ERR)

> *INFOS :*
>
> - proc1 -> return true OR exeption
> - proc2 -> return true OR exeption
> - proc3 -> return object (allows you to change the status of the object)

Someone have a solution, I'm not familiar with RxJs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question isn't clear at the moment. If you wish to make 3 sequential calls for each element in the array you could pipe each of them using `concatMap`s. And if you say these 3 calls for all the elements could be done in parallel, then it could all be enclosed in a `forkJoin`.

I am not yet sure what value you expect in the subscription though. The following code will give an array of responses from `procedure3` for each element.

```js
forkJoin(
  this.list.map(obj =>                           // JS `Array#map`
    this.store.procedure1(obj).pipe(             // 1st call
      concatMap(_ =>
        this.store.procedure2(obj).pipe(         // 2nd call
          concatMap(result =>
            iif(
              () => !!result,                    // conditional 3rd call using RxJS `iif`
              this.store.procedure3(this.var),
              this.store.procedure3(this.var)    // <-- same calls for both conditions?
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
).subscribe(
  ...
);
```

#### Update: include `catchError`

You're almost there. In RxJS, the order of operators piped in is very important. In your case, since the `catchError` is above the `concatMap`s and since it convert the error to a `next` emission, it triggers the following `concatMap`s. The solution is to move the `catchError` blocks below the `concatMap`s.

Try the following

```js
this.list.forEach(obj => {
    var input1 = obj...;
    var input2 = obj...;
    var input3 = obj...;
    
    var obs = this.store.proc1(input1).pipe(
        concatMap(res1 => this.store.proc2(input2).pipe(
            concatMap(res2 => this.store.proc3(input3, "OK")),
            catchError(err2 => this.store.proc3(input3, "ERR"))
        )),
        catchError(err1 => this.store.proc3(input3, "ERR")),
    );
    _obs$.push(obs);
}
```

Comment: In my case the 3 calls of each object in the list must be executed one after the other.
On the other hand, all the objects of the list can be in parallel.
The variable is different for procedure 3, I edited my code.

Comment: I tried to adapt your solution in my code, the procedure1 are all launched, but before they complete, I have the following error: `You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.` procedure2 are never started.

Comment: I assumed the calls `this.store.procedure` calls all return observables. How are the individual function defined?

Comment: Yes, the procedures all return observables: true if it is OK and an exception if an error occurs.
But procedures 2 are never started, the error occurs even before a procedure1 finishes.

Comment: If procedure1 throws an error, then it'll stop the entire stream and will emit an `error` to the subscription. That is how `forkJoin` works by default. If you wish to continue the stream even if any of the observables emit an error, it needs to be converted to a valid emission using `catchError`. Is this what you want?

Comment: I changed my post using part of your solution.
So I managed to perform the 3 procedures in a row for each object in the list.
But the procedures can throw error and I can't handle it.

Comment: For someone saying _"not familiar with RxJS"_ you're relatively quick to grasp it's concepts. Your update is almost there, it needs minor adjustments. I've updated the answer. Please see if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tested this, but the concatMap runs even if there is an error. CatchError are never called.
I managed to fix the problem through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50800838/rxjs-catcherror-not-working-when-piped-from-angular-service/50802968) and your answer works. Thank you.